# D3JS .call() Exception

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently creating a D3JS chain with a .call() at the end. Here is my current chain

```
foo.selectAll('svg')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .classed('someclass', true)
    .call(someFunc);
```

When it reaches the .call() it goes into D3JS function

```
d3_selectionPrototype.call = function(callback) {
    var args = d3_array(arguments);
    callback.apply(args[0] = this, args);
    return this;
};
```

The `this` does not contain anything and returning with the exception of `message: Cannot read property length of undefined`. The unfortunate thing about this is that it happens sporadically. Anyone know of why or how this is happening?

**EDIT**

I am using a javascript framework that implements view composition. The current D3JS call is being made when the model driving the view is first being called.

Comment: because `someFunc` is not defined when you're executing the d3 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue on my own and will leave it up to assist anyone that may have the same issue in the future. I added an **EDIT** to the question so that it helps gives more context to the full issue.

The solution was that since my D3JS chain was being called when the model driving the view is initially setting up there wasn't any thing in the DOM for D3 to select. I moved the chain to be called once the DOM had been rendered and everything was able to run smoothly.